# SVG in Chrome: Attribute transform ≠ CSS transform

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, transform

To be able to use CSS transitions (in Chrome, FF), I've begun translating some SVG attribute styles to CSS styles. However, I ran into a problem in Chrome: translate seems to behave differently if window-zoom is not at 100%.

```
<svg style="position:absolute">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="blue"
    transform="translate(50,50)"></rect>
</svg>
<svg style="position:absolute">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="red"
    style="-webkit-transform:translate(50px,50px)"></rect>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mP493/

[image]

The red triangle should be on the blue triangle, but it's not when I zoom in. Do I have to abandon my plan to translate SVG attribute styles to CSS styles?

Comment: If I post an answer of "Yes", will you accept it? It seems as though this is a thinly-veiled complaint, or bug report or something. _"I'm doing X, but it is not giving me the results I wanted. Does that mean I have to stop doing X to get the results I want?"_ Yes. Yes you do.

Comment: :-) Fair point. I'm new to web-dev, and don't know the SVG specification well enough to say if it's a bug. An answer I was hoping for was "you have to use `50unit` in CSS" or "here's how you can apply transitions to SVG attributes". If this is indeed a bug, and there's no easy work around, "yes" is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I'm going with SMIL animation. These allow transitions for SVG presentation attributes and have <s>good</s> decent support now in FF and Chrome.

Major disadvantage seems to be that it's not simple to undo an animation in reverse from where it's at if the animation is not completed.